# Аутентификация из приложения без SSL

Tags: авторизация, ssl, аутентификация, веб-служба

Есть веб-сервис на сервере без SSL-сертификата и мобильное приложение.

Нужно реализовать аутентификацию из приложения перед пользованием сервисом.

Если бы был сертификат, то можно было бы использовать стандартные методы аутентификации, но как быть, если сертификата нет??

Есть задумка написать собственный алгоритм шифрования пароля. Вроде:

1. Пользователь вводит логин/пароль, нажимает "Вход";
2. Данные шифруются собственным алгоритмом и отправляются на сервер;
3. На сервере данные дешифруются и сравниваются с данными из базы;
4. В случае успеха, генерируется токен со сроком действия, шифруется и отправляется пользователю.
5. Далее токен используется для получения доступа, пока не истечет.

...и все в таком духе.

Только толку от этого шифрования, если злоумышленник может перехватить зашифрованное сообщение и, стем же успехом, использовать его для аутентификации.

Как правильно сделать аутентификацию в данной ситуации??

Comment: А в чем проблема завернуть все в HTTPS?

Comment: У меня сертификата попросту нет. Не задавался вопросом его получения. Что-то читал, что он платный. Почитаю обязательно про получение SSL-сертификата.

Comment: Он а) дешевле ваших ресурсозатрат на то, что вы предлагаете б) вы в результате придете ровно к той же схеме с diffie-hellman для получение секрета сессии и в) его можно получить бесплатно через letsencrypt или http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/AboutUs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет SSL, то весь маш трафик доступен сниферу. В том числе и ваш токен. А еще злодей знает ваш алгоритм шифрования. Он же на странице есть.

Способы есть, но дико неудобные.
Сервер хранит для юзера его логин и постоянный пароль №1. (Получить его можно по емейлу или СМС, один раз - не проблема)

При *первом* обращении к серверу клиент запрашивает у юзера логин и пароль и запоминает их где-то локально.

При *каждом* обращении к серверу, включая первое, генерит случайную строку S, склеивает её с паролем, вычисляет от склейки дайджест MD5 или SHA, передает серверу логин, S и дайджест.
Сервер повторяет вычисление дайджеста от своей копии пароля и строки S.
Есди дайджесты совпали, то запрос считается авторизованным.

Но дешевле купить SSL